# In Sublime Text 3, how can I have next_view-style tab switching that stays within the active group?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, sublime-text-3

Sublime Text 3 has two modes of switching through tabs, which differ in a couple of ways:

1. **prev/next_view**, by default <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd>. Cycles through documents linearly, across all documents and groups in the current window.
2. **prev/next_view_in_stack**, by default <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd>. Cycles through documents by stack order, across only those documents in the active group (the one you're currently working in).

I find the first highly desirable because I can *actually understand* its cycling order, but the fact it cycles across all groups is counter-intuitive to me and regularly trips me up in my work. (I've been using ST3 for months! I'm too used to editors which behave differently.) I want to have something like next_view, but which stays within the current group like next_view_in_stack.

**How can I have linear document cycling behaviour like prev/next_view, but which only switches across tabs in the current group?** If there's a Sublime Text 3 plugin that does the job, that will be a perfectly good solution.

One thoughtful soul wrote the [Sublime Pane Navigation plugin](https://github.com/borist/SublimePaneNavigation) once upon a time which apparently does this, but it was only released for Sublime Text 2 and does not appear to work in Sublime Text 3. (Unless there's something I'm missing).

For a visual example of what I want, suppose I have these documents open:

[image: a screenshot of sublime text with several documents open.]

The left group contains the documents **um, dois** and **tres**, and the right contains **eins** and **zwei.**

Normally next_view will cycle through all five of them in linear order. However, if I'm working in the left group, I want to just cycle linearly through um, dois and tres. If I'm working in the right, I want to cycle back and forth between eins and zwei.

Answer (score 1):

1. Download the contents of [Sublime Page Navigation Plugin](https://github.com/borist/SublimePaneNavigation) and put them in a zipped folder.
2. Rename the **.zip** extension to **.sublime-package**
3. Paste it in /Packages folder

Comment: This plugin appears to be recognised by Sublime Text 3 if I place it in the Installed Packages folder (not Packages), but it does not appear to have any effect. Is it actually compatible with ST3, and is there something extra I should be doing to get it working? Note it was made for ST2, and in fact was the plugin I mentioned in my question.

Comment: I've downvoted this for the time being, but I'll be happy to reverse my vote if this plugin can actually work for ST3 (are there other steps to get it to do that?) and produce the behaviour I'm after.

Comment: I use this with Sublime Text 3. In Package Control, choose Add Repository and add the GitHub URL to the plugin, then install it as normal.